# How to catch the JSON data in frontend REACT.JS which is coming from SOME REMOTE URL(www.example.com) or some server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http, xmlhttprequest

I knew that we can fetch the data from some API in React. but how to get the JSON directly to frontend from other remote web servers like Example:-

1. from example1.com i am posting some json to example2.com
2. exaple2.com is built in REACT.JS,  I dont want to receive the JSON at the Backend.
3. Instead i want to receive the Data frontend React.js

Guys I don't know I have done Correctly i am totally new to React if silly Mistake is there means Just Correct me guys Thank you

**Example:-**
What i have tried

This is a React file running on ***http://localhost:5000*** Which is expecting data from ***http://localhost:3003/***

```
import React,{ Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'
class PostList extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state={
            posts: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('__dirname+http://localhost:3003/',{ 'headers' : { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'}})
            .then(response => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                List of posts
            </div>
        )
    }

}
export default PostList
```

This is Another server running on ***http://localhost:3003/*** which is posting the data to ***http://localhost:5000/***

```
const express = require('express')
const cors=require('cors')
const app = express()
app.use(cors())
const port = 3003
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  console.log(req.body);
  request.post(
    {
    url:'http://localhost:5000/',
    json: {
      unit_name:"hi",
      unit_price:"bye"
        },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    },
  function(error, response, body){
    console.log(body);
    res.send(body);
  });
})
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))
```

Currently I am getting error

```
xhr.js:178__dirname+http://localhost:3003 404 (Not Found)
PostList.js:17 Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

Expected out put is i need to print the JSON in ***http://localhost:5000/*** which is there in ***http://localhost:3003/***

Thank you so much guys, your help means a lot

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see without diving deep into the code is you are sending the GET request, but on the server you don't have the router for this. You only have the POST request acceptance. In this line:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){...}
```

Try to change or add another route for GET:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){...}
```